# How prevent image text moving while resizing the browser window

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

Every time I try to resize my browser window, the img text starts moving to right instead of stay in the same position.

Can you please help to prevent this.

```css
city img{
  margin: -5px auto 0;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
}

.beauty img{
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;

}
.container1{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  
}
.cityText{
  resize: both;
  position: absolute;
  top: 850px;
  left: 480px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: oblique;
  font-style: oblique;
  text-indent: -0.7em;
  line-height: 1.5em; 
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  

}
.cityText:hover{
  background-color: honeydew;
  transition: 2s;
}

.cityText p{
  font-size: medium;
  text-align: right;
}
.beautyText {
  resize: both  ;
  position: absolute;
  top: 810px;
  left: 1180px;
  transform: translate(-10%, -20%);
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: oblique;
  font-style: oblique;
  text-indent: -0.7em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}

.beautyText p {
  font-size: medium;
  text-align: right;
  
}

.beautyText:hover{
  background-color: honeydew;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="city">
    <img src="pictures/1.png">
      <div class="cityText">
        <q>
        Life is what happens <br>
        when you’re busy<br>
        making other plans.</q>
        <p>-John Lennon-</p>
      </div>
      <div class="beauty">
        <img src = "pictures/2.jpg">
        <blockquote class="beautyText">
        <q>
        People are like stained - glass windows.
        They sparkle and shine when the sun is out,
        but when the darkness sets in, their true beauty
        is revealed only if there is a light from within.
        </q>
        <p>-Elisabeth Kubler-Ross-</p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Every time I try to resize my browser window, the `img` text starts moving to right instead of stay in the same position.

Can you please help to prevent this?

Comment: try `position:absolute;` and also try spending some extra time on adding some code to help you out.

Comment: add your html and css

Answer (score 0):

Its just because you used `position: absolute;` use something like what i did.
Compare my code with yours.
Worked or not?

```css
city img{
  margin: -5px auto 0;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
}

.beauty img{
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;

}
.container1{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  
}
.cityText{
  resize: both;
  position: absolute;
  top: 850px;
  left: 480px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: oblique;
  font-style: oblique;
  text-indent: -0.7em;
  line-height: 1.5em; 
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  

}
.cityText:hover{
  background-color: honeydew;
  transition: 2s;
}

.cityText p{
  font-size: medium;
  text-align: right;
}
.beautyText {
    resize: both;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 810px;
    left: 450px;
    transform: translate(-10%, -20%);
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-family: oblique;
    font-style: oblique;
    text-indent: -0.7em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.beautyText p {
  font-size: medium;
  text-align: right;
  
}

.beautyText:hover{
  background-color: honeydew;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="city">
    <img src="pictures/1.png">
      <div class="cityText">
        <q>
        Life is what happens <br>
        when you’re busy<br>
        making other plans.</q>
        <p>-John Lennon-</p>
      </div>
      <div class="beauty">
        <img src = "pictures/2.jpg">
        <blockquote class="beautyText">
        <q>
        People are like stained - glass windows.
        They sparkle and shine when the sun is out,
        but when the darkness sets in, their true beauty
        is revealed only if there is a light from within.
        </q>
        <p>-Elisabeth Kubler-Ross-</p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tommy
Ok i tried to solve your problem.
check the answer again pls.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but is still the same. when i resize browser all text on my website moving to right and website looks very messy. I fighting with this issue 2 days already.

Comment: Your welcome sir.
Ok, if no one answers you, i'll make your codes much better till tonight if you need it thou...

Comment: Thank you again really appreciate your help. Wish you nice day.

Comment: @Tommy
Its normally to see your text's change's because they don't have more free space's.
And i figured out that your position: absolute cause's this problem.
You should remove it and use something else.!